# WPF - Zoom image (inside an constrained sized item control)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, zooming, transform

I would like to zoom an image in WPF and that the image visual render be inside a constrained sized item control.

For example:

```
<Canvas x:Name="m_canvas" MaxWidth="300" MaxHeight="300" >
   <Image Source="..."
      Width="300"
      Height="300" />
</Canvas>
```

The zoom code:

```
var matrix = ((MatrixTransform)m_image.RenderTransform).Matrix;

var center = new Point(m_image.ActualWidth / 2, m_image.ActualHeight / 2);
center = matrix.Transform(center);

matrix.ScaleAt(delta.Scale.X, delta.Scale.Y, center.X, center.Y);

((MatrixTransform)m_image.RenderTransform).Matrix = matrix;
```

The problem is that when I'm zooming the image render size go larger that the canvas limit (300x300). I would like if the image can zoom only in the canvas.

I don't want to limit the max zoom, I want that if the render size of the image is larger that the canvas, it's stay inside. I don't want that it overlap the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clip to the bounds of the `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" ...>
```

But I don't understand why you're using a `Canvas` in the first place. It's likely that there's a much nicer way to approach your particular problem without the need for hard-coded widths and heights and without any `Canvas` at all.

Comment: I'm using a canvas because I'm using touch screen events so I register to manipulation events on the canvas